Can low frequency PWM of a high current resistive load be damaging to the apartment power grid?
I need to digitally control the heating power of a 2 kilowatt heating element connected to 220V. Obviously, there is no need for high-frequency PWM, and 1 hertz should be enough. However, will the constant switching of such a substantial load negatively affect the local power grid and/or appliances connected to the same phase in my apartment? And if it will, how can I smooth the current draw of such a system?

It will be cleanest in terms of EMC if you can arrange the PWM to switch on at zero volts and switch off at zero amps. In other words, a triac and a zero-cross detector.

Your electric stove already does PWM of its many kW electric loads, likely without zero-crossing. 2 kW isn't a large load in a house or building. No need to smooth the current draw, and no easy way of doing that either.
As long as your load has no large inductive or capacitive component, or a large inrush current like a motor, PWM as fast as many Hz should not cause any trouble. Zero crossing switching might be better for your own device.
Light dimmers use PWM by chopping every mains cycle, so at 100 Hz. While 2 kW of lighting would be unusual, especially nowdays with LEDs, it wouldn't be unreasonable. I've used an (upgraded) light dimmer to control a 3 kW kettle, to make it boil very gently.

For long time-constant loads, cycle skipping control as @DaveTweed alluded to is probably easiest, considering there are controllers on the market that implement it. This app note is more for if you want to design a system yourself but can help you figure out what features you want in a prebuilt module.
